# getting rid of root and restructuring json in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a rails4 app. @events are from db, @results come from 3rd party API. I would like to get rid of the root and send it over as both were the same source like in the code I show below.

How can I do that?

Besides this at the moment as you see freebusy is embedded to events and I don't get it why since they seem to separated in the controller. Could sby tell me why this happens?

controller

```
format.json { render json: { events: @events, freebusy: @results }}
```

current json

```
{"events":[{"id":18,"recipientId":2,"recipientName":"Sean Hungarian","senderId":1,
"senderName":"Szilard Magyar","title":"das;fk;aslf","description":"",
"start":"Wed, 16 Dec 2015 00:00:00 +0000","end":"Wed, 16 Dec 2015 02:00:00 +0000","allDay":false,
"recurring":false}], "freebusy":[{"start":"2015-12-31T03:30:00Z","end":"2015-12-31T04:30:00Z","title":"busy","editable":false}]}
```

desired json

```
[{"id":18,"recipientId":2,"recipientName":"Sean Hungarian","senderId":1,"senderName":"Szilard Magyar",
"title":"das;fk;aslf","description":"","start":"Wed, 16 Dec 2015 00:00:00 +0000","end":"Wed, 16 Dec 2015 02:00:00 +0000",
"allDay":false,"recurring":false}, {"start":"2015-12-31T03:30:00Z","end":"2015-12-31T04:30:00Z",
"title":"busy","editable":false}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
format.json { render json: [@events, @results]}
```

But, is that good format of json?